# Intersect a dataframe with a larger one that includes it and remove common rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, intersection

I have two dataframes:

```
df_small = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
                                  [4, 5, 6], 
                                  [7, 8, 9]]),
                     columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

and

```
df_large = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[22, 1, 2, 3, 99], 
                                  [31, 4, 5, 6, 75], 
                                  [73, 7, 8, 9, 23],
                                  [16, 2, 1, 2, 13],
                                  [17, 1, 4, 3, 25],
                                  [93, 3, 2, 8, 18]]),
                     columns=['k', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Now what I want is to intersect the two and only take the rows in `df_large` that that do not contain the rows from `df_small`, hence the result should be:

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[16, 2, 1, 2, 13],
                                   [17, 1, 4, 3, 25],
                                   [93, 3, 2, 8, 18]]),
                     columns=['k', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with `indicator=True` and `left join` and because error is necessary remove duplicates by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) from `df_small`:

```
m = df_large.merge(df_small.drop_duplicates(), how='left', indicator=True)['_merge'].ne('both')
df = df_large[m]
print (df)
    k  a  b  c   d
3  16  2  1  2  13
4  17  1  4  3  25
5  93  3  2  8  18
```

Another solution is very similar, only filtered by `query` and last removed column `_merge`:

```
df = (df_large.merge(df_small.drop_duplicates(), how='left', indicator=True)
              .query('_merge != "both"')
              .drop('_merge', axis=1))
```

Comment: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: @Qubix - I think in `df_small` should be dupes, so necessary remove them before `merge`

Comment: thanks for explaining that 'on' is not necessary, I have removed it from my answer

Answer (score 1):

**Use [DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)**:

```
df_large.merge(df_small,how='outer',indicator=True).query('_merge == "left_only"').drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
    k  a  b  c   d
3  16  2  1  2  13
4  17  1  4  3  25
5  93  3  2  8  18
```

Comment: hmmm, if check carefully it is difference left and outer join what in sample data is not difference but in real should be and also I add drop_duplicates() by OP comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can evade merging and make your code a bit more readable. It's really not that clear what happens when you merge and drop duplicates.
Indexes and Multiindexes were made for intersections and other set operations.

```
common_columns = df_large.columns.intersection(df_small.columns).to_list()
df_small_as_Multiindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df_small)
df_result = df_large.set_index(common_columns).\ 
        drop(index = df_small_as_Multiindex).\ #Drop the common rows
        reset_index() #Not needed if the a,b,c columns are meaningful indexes
```

Comment: Well, it is clear from the machine point of view. If I read someone elses code with no chance to have a look at the underlying data, I do not really get, what was the goal of merge drop duplicates operation. What I want to read is: 1. A = common columns for x,y 2. B = common rows for columns A in x,y 3. x = x without rows B